First timer questions on the core contracts + sdk
I'm evaluating Safe's contracts to use in a new vertical of my company. I'm a regular safe user, but it's the first time I develop on it so I have several questions regarding the implementation details.

Can I deploy a contracts with a 1/n for erc20 transfer and 2/2 "guardian style" recovery? So, any signer does not need to be multisig but if I lose my signer, i can recovery with a 2/2.
Can I use the SDK to generate the Raw Transaction Data +  hash in a backend? (I ask this cos most sdks are geared towards frontend, and this is a pain with other sdks i have tried).
What I need is to be able to split the transaction data generation from the signing, our app is a light client, and contains zero sdks. NOTE: I think i can achive similar funcionality of my #2  question by using proposeTransaction.
Can I use a factory to precalculate the contract address?
Are the signatures just regular ecdsa signatures?

Hope the title is not too generic and question gets closed or something :D
Thanks a lot


Absolutely, you can find more information about of this here.
Yes, you can use the SDK in the backend. You can also make calls to Safe's Transaction Service API
Yes, you can use the contract directly or use the SDK to create a Safe object from a given configuration (and get its address), and later deploy it.
Safe supports different types of signatures, including standard ECDSA. You can find examples of how to use it with Safe{Core} SDK here.

Hope it helps! Best, Louis

I was not expecting so many "YES"! Thanks for such quick reply. Looking forward to start building with Safe!

I noticed that deploySafe needs a PK in order to work (directly or via 1193).
Is it possible to decouple the data from the signing? Or my only way is to either do my own factory, or reverse engineer the sdk? :(
